# Error attempting to build Web Application that was built with Visual Studio 2017 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have an ASP.Net Web Application Project that was created using Visual Studio 2017.  The Project includes some class libraries but nothing fancy.  The Target Framework is  4.5 and  the project is currently using c# 6.  The project works great, except when we try to load it with Visual Studio 2015. We get the error

> Microsoft.Net.Compliers is only supported on MS Build v15.0 and above.

Is there a way to set up the project in vs 2017 to allow  users using Visual Studio 2015 to build and run the application?  The project doesn't use any of the latest technology.  Its NOT .Net Core and it doesn't use c# 7.  Thanks.